# Issue while reindexing customer_grid 2.1.7

Tags: magento-2.1.7, indexing, customer-grid

I have migrated the data from m1.9 to m2.1.7 but I find that customers are not loaded into the grid where I checked the table customers are present.

As I googled I tried to update the indexer_status table and do a reindex for customer_grid

It throws me "Invalid foreign key" any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by disabling one of my customer module